# How can i get appropriate .properties file using servlet when i have multiple .properties file in web-inf folder?

Tags: xml, jsp, servlets

```
<param-name>Language</param-name>
    <param-value>en</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>Country</param-name>
    <param-value>US</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>Language</param-name>
    <param-value>jp</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>Country</param-name>
    <param-value>JP</param-value>
</context-param>
```

this is my web.xml file code.

```
ServletContext app = getServletContext();
        localeLang = app.getInitParameter("Language");
        localeCountry = app.getInitParameter("Country");
```

this is my jsp code where i'm accessing properties files based on language and country.
i.e., when lang is en and country is US i need to access en_US.properties file and when lang is jp and Country is JP i need to access jp_JP.properties file like that when i have 100 properties file then how can i access properties file based on appropriate lang and country?

Comment: anybody guide me please?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than directly accessing the properties files you should consider using the [`ResourceBundle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html) mechanism, which is designed for precisely this situation. Put the properties files in `WEB-INF/classes` instead of just in `WEB-INF`, and name them all with a common prefix

```
messages.properties
messages_en.properties
messages_en_GB.properties
messages_jp.properties
```

Use `ResourceBundle.getBundle("messages", new Locale(localeLang, localeCountry))` and it will pull properties from `messages_lang_country.properties` when they exist in there, and fall back to `messages_lang.properties` and `messages.properties` if necessary.